# Preventing concurrency using Combine

Tags: swift, combine

I have to use a third party SDK to communicate with a Bluetooth device. The SDK only allows one call at a time and a call cannot be cancelled. I have abstracted each call to the SDK with a layer returning Combine publishers.

```
struct AbstractedSDKLayer {
  func getBatteryLevel() -> AnyPublisher<Float, Error> { ... }
  func getVersion() -> AnyPublisher<String, Error> { ... }
  ...
}
```

My problem occurs when my UI is calling multiple times `getBatteryLevel()` for instance, because of some actions triggering refresh.

I have tried to create a custom operator to delay subscription to upstream publisher (because the SDK call is triggered when a subscription is received, using a `Deferred { Future }`). My idea was to have a "pool" of SDK pending requests, processing one and going on the next one. But well, I think I'm missing some understanding of Combine tools (Subscriber, Subscription, demand...) and my code is not working. I have made some tests using a connectable publisher but with still no success. From my point of view, it seems that most native Combine operator controls the publishing process but not the subscription process.

My Android colleague has handled this usecase by using a Kotlin coroutine Mutex.

What is the best way to do this with Combine?

Comment: What do you want to have happened when a second call to `getBatteryLevel` comes? do you want to subscribe to the same publisher?

Comment: Eventually but it's not mandatory, the 2nd call can be queued to be done after. My main issue is to prevent concurrent calls to the SDK, so even a call to `getBatteryLevel` cannot be done until a call to `getVersion` is running.

Comment: Returning a shared publisher is straightforward; more so than queueing. What does a call to each method actually do here? Does it return a publisher that keeps publishing battery levels every so often? Or does it publish it once and complete?

Comment: Yes, that's what I've done at first try, using a `.share()` operator. This worked quite well but the concurrency is still an issue when calling another method on the SDK (`getBatteryLevel`  and `getVersion` for instance). Currently, each publisher sends a value and completes.

Comment: I don't think Combine was designed to solve synchronization. Look into using `DispatchSemaphore` to synchronize access to a finite resource.